# Spring Security Oauth2 /oauth/authorize endpoint doesn't prompt me for a username and password, just automatically redirects to confirm_acces page

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I followed the tutorial https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v#creating-an-oauth2-authorization-server for setting up an authorization server using Spring Security OAuth2.  Everything seems to be working fine and I'm able to test getting an authorization token as outlined in the tutorial.

What I've noticed however is that when the authorization server starts up, it's logging me in automatically using my laptop username which is Patrick.  The AuthenticationManager I'm using is backed by a database where my username also happens to be Patrick.  So I'm just trying to understand this behaviour.  Why does it do it?  Is there some way to disable that functionality?  Should I be concerned?

If I updated my profile in the database and change my username to something other than Patrick, then it doesn't automatically authenticate me and I'm prompted to login by my authentication server.

Any clarification on this is appreciated :)